# local notification custom sound is representing sound with old notification sound

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I scheduled notifications by setting custom sound after that I scheduled another notification with other custom sound . The issue is the second notification's sound is the same with the oldest one; How to solve the issue;
I use
`flutter_local_notification` plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it as follows. When creating the AndroidNotificationDetails, you need to set a unique id for each notification with a custom sound.

Here's an example in Flutter using the flutter_local_notifications plugin:

```
Future<void> scheduleNotificationWithCustomSound() async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your_unique_notification_channel_id',
    'notification_channel_name',
    'notification_channel_description',
    playSound: true,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('your_custom_sound'),
  );

  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(
    sound: 'your_custom_sound.caf',
  );

  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    'Notification Title',
    'Notification Body',
    scheduledDate,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
  );
}
```

In the code above, make sure to change 'your_unique_notification_channel_id', and 'your_custom_sound' to be unique for each notification. This way, each notification will have its own custom sound and won't override the previous one.

This should resolve the issue of notifications sharing the same sound.